# How can I use KVO on SKSpriteNode position property

Tags: sprite-kit, key-value-coding

I would like to use KVO to observe changes to the SKSpriteNode position property, but it doesn't seem to work. Is SKNode's position property observable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, it is not. SK behind the scenes is a C++ engine that bypasses most of Objective-C's overhead, like for instance KVO (KVC will still work cause that's entirely on you).

Unlike in UI(Kit) apps, most values of most objects change often anyway, so if you're interested in changes to a property it's faster to simply check it every frame using SKScene's `update:` or (better) `didSimulatePhysics` methods.

Comment: You totally answered my question. I was learning KVO and I couldn't do it with SKSpriteNode so I thought I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I wasted time writing KVO code when I should have looked at what SKNode, SKSpriteNode etc inherit from. Just goes to show, know the objects you are using.