# SpriteKit: How can I determine when methods like applyImpulse on a physicsbody are done?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios8

I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746925/how-can-i-use-kvo-on-skspritenode-position-property) how to use the update() function to monitor properties like "position" on an SKNode but I don't see how I would know how methods like  `[node.physicsBody applyImpulse:vector]` has finished.

```
-(void)someMethod {
    _monitorOn = YES;
    [_node.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(10,10)];
}
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
   if( _monitorOn == YES ) {
       NSLog(@"node position: %f,%f", _node.position.x, _node.position.y);
   }
   // When will this be turned off?
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways to check if the effect of applyImpulse is completed:

```
if (_node.physicsBody.resting) {
   // Node is at rest, do something
}
```

You'll often find that the resting property is never set because your sprite is moving very slowly (particularly with circle nodes). Therefore, it's better to check if the speed is nearly zero.

```
static inline CGFloat speed(const CGVector v)
{
    return sqrtf(v.dx*v.dx+v.dy*v.dy);
}

if (speed(_node.physicsBody.velocity) < kSmallValue) {
   // Node is moving very slowly, do something
}
```

Comment: yes, velocity check is very helpful (!) since the node reaches the destination and stops moving long before the .resting bit is set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`applyImpulse` simply adds some velocity to your `_node`; it only does so when you call it and is "finished" after one frame.  I think what you're really looking for is when `_node` stops moving (which will happen the physics engine determines that `_node`'s velocity is zero). To check for this, you can look at `SKPhysicsBody`'s [`resting`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/resting) property. Simply check for it in your `update:` loop; when it's `true` your `_node` has stopped.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
     if( _monitorOn == YES ) {
         NSLog(@"node position: %f,%f", _node.position.x, _node.position.y);
     }

     if( _node.physicsBody.resting ) {
         NSLog(@"node is stopped");
     }
 }
```

**Note:** *You'll probably want to set an addition flag somewhere that you can use to see if you should be checking if `_node` is `resting`, otherwise you're going to get a ton of "node is stopped" messages.*

```
-(void)someMethod {
    _monitorOn = YES;
    _appliedImpulse = YES;
    [_node.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(10,10)];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
     if( _monitorOn == YES ) {
         NSLog(@"node position: %f,%f", _node.position.x, _node.position.y);
     }

     if( _appliedImpulse && _node.physicsBody.resting ) {
         _appliedImpulse = NO;
         NSLog(@"node is stopped");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Actually, I can put the .resting check under the _monitorOn check but the trouble is that I get quite a large amount of updates after the node has actually stopped moving - like 80 updates, 50 of which are in the actual last position. Thanks!

Comment: And you're setting `_monitorOn` to `NO` when `_node.physicsBody.resting == YES`?

Comment: yes. pseudo: if( _monitor ) { if( _node.resting ) { _monitor = NO; } else { ...} }

Comment: Ok, just checking. It might just be that the physics engine still sees `_node` as moving even though the amount it's moving is too small to register on screen or even in your `NSLog` entries. @Aidan's velocity check will work if checking `resting` is taking too long for your liking.

Comment: yup - I can see now that the node is still "moving" according to the velocity math which explains the true definition of "resting" (absence of velocity) but that tiny velocity is not enough to change its position. Thanks!